# What is a Win32 Exception the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes, process.start

I have a problem with Process.Start(), i want it to open specified file when I double click on tree node.

This is my code where it should open file

```
 String path = "C:\\Users\\........\\something";

        private void treePrica_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try {

                String TreeNodeName = treePrica.SelectedNode.ToString().Replace("TreeNode: ", String.Empty);
                MessageBox.Show(this.path + "\\" + TreeNodeName);

                Process.Start(this.path + "\\" + TreeNodeName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

When i double click on any of the nodes containing .txt file it throws exception like this

[image: Win32 Exception]

Comment: It's saying it can't find the file. Debug your code to find the path that it's looking for, and see if that is correct. If it is correct, then there's a permissions issue.

Comment: Consider using File.Open instead of Process to open a file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did debug and the path is correct, I'll try File.Open and report back, Thank you both

Comment: I used File.Open and now it throws new exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find a file

Comment: What does your `MessageBox` show as the value for the filename?

Answer (score 0):

just use string path = @"c:/something"; and make sure you add the extension to the total path!